# The type name 'T' could not be found

Tags: c#

I'm working on generic and ref parameters , I have initlized the nums in main function and have created the generic function and passed these nums to that function, but its saying that that called function is not readable , here is code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericMethodAppl {
   
   class Program {
      
      static void Swap<T>( T a,  T b) {
        
        Console.WriteLine(a,b);
      }
      
      static void Main(string[] args) {
         int a, b;
         a = 10;
         b = 20;
         Swap<T>( T a, T b);
         
        
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried calling function but didn't work out

Comment: If the purpose of your lesson is to learn how to call generic methods, then go learn about that. When calling a generic method, you either need to provide the generic argument(s) or let them be inferred. In the context of your (intended) method call to `Swap`, there is no `T`, only `int`.

Comment: all you need to do is call Swap(a,b);

Comment: I don't know any overload of `Console.WriteLine` that would accept a `T`. What is the *purpose* of that `Swap`-function?

Comment: `T` (or any other identifier) is just a placeholder used when declaring a class or method in a generic way, once it comes to using said class or method you need to actually specify the type (or let the compiler figure it out). This means that the "type" `T` only exists within your function/ class and not outside of it, when calling it from outside the generic type `T` needs to be turned into a concrete type, in this case `int`, which means you need to call your method like so: `Swap<int>(a, b)`. P.S in some cases such as this the compiler can figure out the type on its own, like `Swap(a,b)`

Comment: @vhr Give a man a fire and he's warm for a day, but set fire to him and he's warm for the rest of his life.

Comment: please read this article about generics which should explain it in more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics and generic methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Answer (score 1):

1 : You musn't specify the type in front of parameters when you are calling a function

2 : You are using T as an int, so after the name of the function you have replace T by an int, you can do it simply by replacing `<T>` with `<int>`

```cs
Swap<int>(a,b);
```

Bonus : Because the type of your parameters and the generic type used by the function are the same, you don't even have to specify behind the name of the function the type you'll be using

```cs
Swap(a,b);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `T` in the method definition is a placeholder for the type. When you actually use the method later, you use the real type:

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
     int a, b;
     a = 10;
     b = 20;
     Swap<int>(a,b);                 
  }
```

... or let type inference figure it out for you:

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {
     int a, b;
     a = 10;
     b = 20;
     Swap(a,b);                 
  }
```